# Android: WebView opens links in my app on my phone, but in browser on emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I have a `WebView` in my app where I load some internet address. I want when a user clicks on a link on that internet page, the default browser to be opened with the respective link. And I have implemented the following:

```
    //set the addBanner
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.adBanner);
    WebViewClient wvc = new WebViewClient(){
        //open adds in new browser
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(url));
            wv.getContext().startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    };
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(wvc);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); //this was desperate attempt :)
    wv.loadUrl(AdvertisementURL);
```

It works very well in emulator (Nexus 5, API 23; and some other emulators, too) - when I click on a link, new Browser activity is opened with the expected page on it. But on my phone (Android 4.2.2) - the links open in my app, and not in an external browser.

Why is this happening? And is there a way to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Really no ideas? :(